# Create a list by combining each index in 2 lists

Tags: python

Given the fact that I have two lists x,y each containing the x and y co-ordinated respectively that correspond to each point on every index of these lists. How do I create a list out of this ?

Meaning, `x[0]`,`y[0]` correspond to one point, and `x[1]`,`y[1]` correspond to another point.

Edit: I want to do it in bumpy

Comment: Use the builtin function `zip(x, y)`.

Comment: If you are dealing with lists of numerical data, you might want to use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [7,8,9]

print zip(x, y)

# [(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9)]
```